# Unable to configure signer for delegate using walletAdapterIdentity (metaplex UMI)

Tags: metaplex, nft, solana-wallet-adapter, umi, delegate

Getting an error `publicKey.toBase58 is not a function` when calling `delegateStaingV1`

I've spent quite some time making sure my UMI instance is setup correctly to use the `walletAdapterIdentity` plugin and `createSignerFromWalletAdapter`, but i believe my error may lie within this somewhere (perhaps the way im stating the `signer`.

Should i be using `umi.use(signerIdentity(createSignerFromWalletAdapter(umi, wallet)));` or should the UMI instance be configured solely with `createUmi`?

I was following the docs at:
https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/umi/tree/main/docs
https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/delegates#staking-delegate-pnft-only

Here is a snippet of my code base (VueJs):

```
const connection = new Connection(endpoint)
const wallet = useWallet()

const umi = createUmi(connection)
    .use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet))
    .use(mplTokenMetadata())

const signer = createSignerFromWalletAdapter(wallet);
umi.identity = signer
umi.payer = signer
umi.use(signerIdentity(createSignerFromWalletAdapter(umi, wallet)));

const stakingDelegate = new PublicKey('publicKeyPlaceholder');
const mint = new PublicKey('publicKeyPlaceholder');

const delegate = async () => {
    try {
        await delegateStakingV1(umi, {
            mint,
            tokenOwner: signer.publicKey,
            authority: signer,
            authorizationRules: new PublicKey('eBJLFYPxJmMGKuFwpDWkzxZeUrad92kZRC5BJLpzyT9'),
            delegate: stakingDelegate,
            tokenStandard: TokenStandard.ProgrammableNonFungible,
        }).sendAndConfirm(umi)

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error delegating:', error);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

When i change my `signer` from:

> `const signer = createSignerFromWalletAdapter(umi, wallet);`

to:

> `const signer = createSignerFromWalletAdapter(wallet);`

The error I'm receiving becomes a wallet adapter issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `PublicKey` class from legacy web3.js as opposed to the `PublicKey` type that Umi expects — i.e. a simple base58 `string` opaque type.

You need to replace things like:

```
const stakingDelegate = new PublicKey('publicKeyPlaceholder');
const mint = new PublicKey('publicKeyPlaceholder');
```

to:

```
import { publicKey } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";

const stakingDelegate = publicKey('publicKeyPlaceholder');
const mint = publicKey('publicKeyPlaceholder');
```

[See Umi's documentation regarding `PublicKeys` here](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/umi/blob/main/docs/publickeys-signers.md#public-keys).

There's also a helper package to help you convert to and from legacy web3.js classes if you had to convert a `PublicKey` class into a `PublicKey` type from Umi:

```
import { fromWeb3JsPublicKey } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-web3js-adapters";

const stakingDelegate = fromWeb3JsPublicKey(stakingDelegateFromWeb3Js);
const mint = fromWeb3JsPublicKey(mintFromWeb3Js);
```

[See Umi's documentation regarding Web3.js adapters here](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/umi/blob/main/docs/web3js-adapters.md#web3js-adapters).